# spring cloud dataflow and airflow

Tags: airflow, spring-cloud-dataflow

We have airflow as workflow management tool to schedule/monitor tasks and also some have applications using Spring cloud dataflow for loose coupling across processes via producer and consumer talking message bus Kafka and Grafana dashboards for UI (ETL). Kubernetes and AWS (EKS) are options for deployments.

We are starting to creating data pipelines which will have sources( Files on S3 or server or databases), processors( custom applications, AL/ML pipelines ) and destinations (Kafka, s3, databases, ES). I am planning to use airflow to manage overall management of pipelines and tasks within pipeline via SCDF based applications or future applications written python as AL/ML piece expands. Is this correct approach or can I let go of one over other?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements, SCDF would fit and provide options to manage your streaming data pipelines. 
While you can still research to find any other possible approaches, I can provide some more hints on what SCDF provides to meet some of your requirements.

- SCDF provides out of the box apps which you can extend/customize. These apps include S3 source and sink which you can use out of the box. For a complete list of out of the box apps, you can refer the page [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/)
- Apparently, SCDF has Kubernetes deployer which you can work on any Kubernetes based platforms. You can configure your K8s specific properties as a set of kubernetes deployer properties when you deploy the applications.
- You can embed a python based application as a processor/transformer in the streaming data pipeline. You can check this [receipe](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/polyglot/) from the SCDF site to know more about this.
- You can also embed `tensorflow` application as a [processor](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tensorflow/tree/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-processor-tensorflow) application inside a pipeline.